# How to save a scene

Tags: opengl, boost, qt5, glsl

I have made a application which renders geometric objects.

Now i want the ability to save a scene to a file and load it from the file.

I have no clue how this should be done and i have few questions regarding this.

1) What file format are the scenes saved as , initially i thought of saving the scenes as a XML file  i tried looking into some popular formats like .max , .3ds but they don't seem to be XML files.

2) How do i save data ?

In this particular example i have drawn a circle.

[image]

i am using QT tree model and this is how my  Class structure looks like.[![enter image description here

[image]
 I have a tree item with data type Container*

Container has a data type Geometry*

Geometry is a polymorphic class interface for  all the geometry types using virtual function like draw etc.

Circle class has two data members float Radius , int segments.

Rectangle class has three data members.

How do i save this to a file and load it back.

Comment: Serilization is what you need  , read this  http://www.ocoudert.com/blog/2011/07/09/a-practical-guide-to-c-serialization/

Comment: @sumitkang even though you are right, you gave the wrong link as explanation because Qt has it's own way of serializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this tutorial: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtcore-serialization-savegame-example.html

Basically the idea is simple. When you save, you serialize everything you need. When you load, you deserialize what you serialized.